# Useful design patterns for creating a neat Python Web App

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, design-patterns

We decided to refactor our code as almost every new feature was implemented as a form of a hack. Would to get some tips on what design patterns would be useful to have in a web app. Things like Factory or Facade don't suit, I feel those are more suited for libraries and not a web app.

The gist of the web app is that it is a sort of translator that understands a user's queries and creates large queries to our DBs. It's a sort of search service. We have a ton of features and configuration that keep stepping on each other's functionalities and we have to add ugly hacks to overcome them. Hoping to have a good base that lets creating long complex chain of rules easier to modify.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to give practical & concrete advice in cases where all you have is a general overview of the project's functionality. But you may start gradually rewriting clusters of deeply intertwined classes with [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles. Don't be too ambitious and attempt to refactor your entire codebase at once without a solid plan and timeframe.

I'd especially emphasize the one/single-responsibility principle, which seems to be the largest cause of trouble. There have been [entire books](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44936.Refactoring) written on refactoring. You may also check the [C2 Wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?CategoryRefactoring) to find tips that might be applicable to you. There is no design pattern that'll act as a magical cure. Reduce complexity by simplifying the web of connections between your 'modules': crossroads, especially non-explicit ones, are bad.

Comment: Avoided giving info since don't know how my managers would react. Other than that I agree you. No DP that can act as a silver bullet.